# Appium: Element is not interactable error is getting displayed while tapping on the checkbox

Tags: mobile, appium, emulation

1. Tried: `xpath= //*[@id="mktoCheckbox_52362_0"]`,

> Console Error: Element is not interactable.

2. Tried: `Xpath= //[@id="mktoForm_2768"]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/label`,

> console error: Element is not interactable.

3. Tried: `xpath= //*[text()='I agree to the ']`,

> clicking on 'License Agreement' link and open pdf file in other tab.

Applied all the above `xpath` but still got no result. Please provide some solution to this problem.

Comment: Here is the HTML: <label for="mktoCheckbox_52362_0"><span face="helvetica, arial, sans-serif" style="font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 12px;">I agree to the <a href="https://info.couchbase.com/rs/302-GJY-034/images/2017-10-30_License_Agreement.pdf" target="_blank" title="License Agreement" id="">License Agreement</a></span></span></label>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to automate this page: https://info.couchbase.com/couchbase_server_mobile.html

- If you want to open the license agreement in a new tab - the relevant XPath would be

  ```
  //a[text()='License Agreement']
  ```

  [image]
- If you want to tick the checkbox associated with the license agreement you need this one:

  ```
  //input[@name='termsandConditions']
  ```

  [image]

In both case it's better to use [Explicit Wait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to ensure that the element is clickable prior to attempting to interact with it via i.e. [ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function

Going forward if you're working on mobile automation you can consider using [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which provides [`Copy Unique XPath` feature](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+Copy+Unique+XPath), it can make your life easier when it comes to defining an element locator

[image]

Comment: When trying with //input[@name='termsandConditions']. Getting error as: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Comment: And when applied----------------------------------------------------------------------- WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='termsandConditions']")));
   element.click();--------------------Console error: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@name='termsandConditions'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)